Spinning single phase induction motor while having no power
I have a single phase induction motor connecting to a spindle.
The motor is connected to a electronic speed controller and I believe it has a series capacitor.
If spindle are to be spin while motor power is off (open power circuit), would it cause any damage or anything that should be concerned?

Think about what happens when you remove power.  Doesn't the motor coast?

Thank for the reply. yes, the motor do coast and nothing happens. So it should be safe, i am just too paranoid if it could cause any problem

There are different types of induction motors. The single-phase motor with one capacitor could be either of these configurations (source of images):


There are other motors with the combination of the caps that you can read about in the link.
These motors usually come with a type of squirrel cage rotor.

The winding on these rotors is closed and does not come out of the rotor (no brush). The residual magnetic field on these rotors is very low. Meaning, that if the stator is open and you start rotating the shaft, the generated voltage is very low.
There are types of induction motors with brushed rotors. These are the same as above. They don't generate any power unless the rotor is connected to a power source (usually DC).
You can do a simple test to see if the motor is generating power. One easy way is to put a voltage meter across the motor terminal and start rotating it. If you see a considerable voltage generated, it might not be safe to do so.
If you don't have a voltage meter at hand, the other way would be to short the motor terminals. Then try to spin the rotor. If you see more resistance on the rotor spinning than when the terminal is open, then it is generating power and might not be safe to do so. (depending on the generated voltage)
